# Is plastic paint a possible solution for a wall with humidity?

Tags: paint, humidity

I have a wall that often gets wet. It's a very thin wall and I think it's water that somehow just infiltrates. This happens mostly in the rainy season.

I am not looking for the ultimate permanent solution. For now I am just looking for a cheap solution, that may keep things looking a bit better.

Would painting with plastic paint help to keep water out

Comment: "a wall that gets wet in the rainy season" points to a leak in the exterior wall, go look for that and patch it.

Comment: @ratchetfreak that has been done this summer. In any case this is in 4th floor and it's not something I can easily do myself. I don't want to spend too much money with it either. I am just looking for a temporary solution that makes life better.

Comment: My gut feeling is that paint of any sort will bubble and blister and not adhere well to a wall that becomes damp. This might be a problem that does not have a very simple cheap solution.

Comment: this sounds like a good way to grow mold by trapping the moisture. Thinking outside the box, have you tried a de-humidifyer? Or even a fan might help by circulating the air way from the problem area.

Comment: Please clarify the situation.  Is this an interior wall getting wet from a bathroom shower and being visible on the wall outside the bathroom?  Or maybe it is an exterior wall getting wet from rain outside and soaking the adjacent interior wall?

Answer (score 5):

Trapping the water in the wall is no solution, it will only wreck the wall more quickly.

Any paint you put on there will fall off the wall, as it will be pushed off by the water.  I use a lot of different paints from LPU to powdercoat.  Nothing I know of will do what you want.

Comment: thank you. Not exaclty what I wanted to ear, but a very valid answer!

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that it's not a leak, you have to put the vapor barrier on the outer part of the house, not the inner part (because keeping moisture out of the wall area is the idea). This problem often comes from having air conditioning inside, and high humidity outside.

If it also gets cold in your area and you spend lots of time indoors, you may need another vapor barrier on the inner part of the wall- again, to keep moisture out of the wall. Paints can help with moisture, but you would need to paint the exterior of the house in this case (unless you have more recent construction, indicating materials like tyvek were used- then you might want to check the roof for leaks).

For what it's worth proper moisture barrier would really depend on your location: [Understanding Vapor Barriers](http://buildingscience.com/documents/digests/bsd-106-understanding-vapor-barriers)